# where to look in jmockit to debug expectation mismatches?

Tags: jmockit

I'm mocking a method with a rather complex parameter list in jmockit, and I'm suspecting that some things are not sufficiently 'equals'. Where in jmockit might one place a breakpoint to observe the comparison process and step through it?